# JAVA JTAB multiple compoments

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, components, jtabbedpane

I'm begging with JAVA Swing. But when I use my JPanel can I only add one JTextPane. How can I do so I can add multiple.

Here's is what I do

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JTP = new JTextPane();
JTP.setBackground(Color.black);
JTP.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
Lines = new JTextPane();
new BorderLayout();
panel.add(JTP, BorderLayout.WEST);
new BorderLayout();
panel.add(Lines, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

And there's is no errors. I know i not have giving you all the code but it's work.

Answer (score 1):

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

This create a JPanel which uses a `FlowLayout` by default.

```
new BorderLayout();
```

This statement does nothing because you don't have a reference to the BorderLayout, to you can't use it as a layout manager on any panel.

But there is no need to use a BorderLayout for you panel, since a FlowLayout can display multiple components at one time. The problem is that the text pane needs a "preferred size" before it can be using with a layout manager.

For something simple why don't you just start with a JTextArea since it is easer to use. You can create the text area with code like:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
```

and it will create  a text area with a preferred size to display 5 lines of text with about 20 characters on each line.

Then you create two text areas and add them to your panel.

Of course any time you use a text area you should probably add it to a JScrollPane:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
panel.add( scrollPane );
```

and then add the scrollPane to the panel.

Comment: I need to use JtextPane because I need multiple colors in it.

Comment: @ZinXanCraft, so get your code working first with a text area since it is simple to use. Then once you understand the basics you can use a JTextField. The only difference is that you are now responsible for determining the preferred size of the text pane since it doesn't support the row/columns concept.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you are only seeing one TextField because you aren't properly using BorderLayout.

EDIT: You said you want to change background colors, you can do that to a JTextField and a JTextArea. Check the docs! It's one line of code.

You are supposed to explicitly set the layout of the JPanel to BorderLayout like this :

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

OR

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Even simpler, you don't need to use BorderLayout.

JPanel, by default, is assigned a FlowLayout which is capable of neatly handling more than one JComponent.  Try using a JTextField or JTextArea instead of a JTextPane.

If you need to use a JTextPane because of a certain layout goal, then try the code examples I listed above.

Good luck. Don't be afraid to refer to the official Oracle docs/tutorials for Swing Layouts

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html